# Setting state of nested element, multilevel array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app with a state element like this:

```
state = {

  options: {

    xaxis: {
      categories: []
    }
  }

}
```

However, in this function, when I try to set the state of categories I get an error that it isn't expecting a format with periods like options.xaxis.categories

```
this.setState({
  options.xaxis.categories: this.state.resultDates
});
```

How can I properly set the state of that array element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax. This is correct syntax.

```
this.setState({
  options: {
    ...this.state.options,
    xaxis: {
      ...this.state.options.xaxis,
      categories: this.state.resultDates
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: wow, I was way off! I don't know why I couldn't find that documented anywhere. I really appreciate it, that worked great!